# How to do GET API Request with URL params?

Tags: java, rest, get, query-string

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
urlApi="https://localhost:123/demo/api/v1/rows/search?";
WebTarget webTarget = client.target(urlApi);
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : queryParams.entrySet()) {
    webTarget.queryParam(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
webTarget.queryParam("searchConditions",webTarget.queryParam("mobileNo","+9999999999"));

Invocation.Builder builder = webTarget.request();

builder.header("id", "ABC");
String asB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("ABC:PWD".getBytes("utf-8"));
logger.debug("Calling  API "+urlApi);
builder.header("Authorization", "Basic "+asB64);
builder.header("Content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);     
response = builder.get();
responseData = response.readEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(responseData);
```

I am trying to do GET request with searchCondition as Key and value as `{mobileNo="+919999999999"}`, I am unable to get this to work.

Apart from that, how can I print the Request "Headers" along with "Query params"? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to encode the value inputs, something like this:

```
webTarget.queryParam("searchCondition", URLEncoder.encode("{mobileNo=\"+919999999999\"}", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()));
```

UDPATE:
Example of the rest  client with Spring:

```
@Test
public void testStack() throws Exception {
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    String fooResourceUrl="http://localhost:8080/usersParam?";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String parameter = "{mobileNo=\"+919999999999\"}";

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(fooResourceUrl + "parameter=" + URLEncoder.encode(parameter, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString() ), String.class);
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And this would be the rest service:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/usersParam")
    public User getUsersInfo(@RequestParam String parameter) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
         System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(parameter, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString() ));
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Its still not working man. https://localhost:123/demo/api/v1/rows/search?searchConditions={mobileNo=+919899999999} This works in post man...

Comment: See updated response. I have done a service (userParams) and request a parameter (your searchConditions). The only problem is that the server shall decode the parameter values too.